# Is it possible to put the SDL .lib, .dll, and header files somewhere so I can just type #include <SDL2.h> in a visual studio 2017 RC project?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, windows-10, visual-studio-2017

My question is, is there a place(s) I can put the SDL .lib, dll, and header files, or process I can do, so when I create a C++ project I can just type `#incldue <SDL2.h>` instead of having to mess about with the project settings every time. Also making a project template is not a desirable solution to this question. Also, the IDE I am using is visual studio 2017 RC, running on windows 10. I also have access to the SDL source file so I could do something with the .c files if necessary.

Note that the desired solution would allow the programmer to include sdl in the same way they would include something like `#include <stdio.h>`, no extra work.

Comment: My advice is to not put the files inside the Visual Studio folders. Instead set the paths in your IDE using a property page: https://msdn.microsoft.com/query/dev12.query?appId=Dev12IDEF1&l=EN-US&k=k(VS.ToolsOptionsPages.Projects.VCDirectories)&rd=true

Comment: @drescherjm good information I gave you an upvote for it. I'd like to see how to do what I described in the question though, partially just because I am curious.

Comment: Sorry, I will let someone else do that. Myself I use `CMake` to generate all of my Visual Studio projects so I actually would do this in a completely different way (with batch files that set environment variables for `CMake` finders to direct `CMake` to find the versions of the packages I want in a build tree) but I just wanted to mention the official way..

Comment: With that said I would expect there is likely a duplicate here about Visual Studio Property Pages.

Comment: @drescherjm when you use CMake can you still use the visual studio debugger? I was actually pondering using CMake to do my building, but I really like the debugger that visual studio has. Also visual studio can handle building my projects for IOS, and linux through SSH, but I think CMake can to.

Comment: Yes of course. I use the debugger daily. I have used `CMake` for every project developed at work since 2008. Not sure about iOS. I have used my `CMake` projects from time to time in `linux` but not as often as I thought when I started. The biggest reason is time.

Comment: @ holycatcrusher, although "making a project template is not a desirable solution to this question", I suggest you make it. You can find instructions at (https://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-SDL-with-Visual-Studio-2017). Regards.

Answer (score -1):

Although "making a project template is not a desirable solution to this question",  I suggest, regarding Visual Studio 2017 Community, make it. You can find instructions at ([wikihow.com/Set-Up-SDL-with-Visual-Studio-2017](https://www.wikihow.com/Set-Up-SDL-with-Visual-Studio-2017)). Following is an overview.

**A. Downloading SDL and Creating Empty project.**

**A.1. Create folder SDL, and put folder *SDL2-2.0.8* in it.** In directory (disk) C:, create (by right click > New > Folder) new folder called *SDL*. If desired, you can choose another directory or folder, and another name for the new folder. Click at https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php. Scroll to the bottom of the page and find *Development Libraries*. Under *Windows:* click the first entry: *SDL2-devel-2.0.8-VC.zip (Visual C++ 32/64-bit)*. Drag (or, by right click, copy and paste) folder *SDL2-2.0.8* from the window where it is downloaded, into folder C: > SDL.

**A.2. Create *Empty project***. Open Visual Studio Community 2017, and create *Empty project*. In the *Name:* text box, type *SDLproject*. After the *Location* text box, click *Browse...* and navigate C: > SDL. Click *Select folder*. The *Location* now is C:\SDL. Make sure the *Create directory for solution* box is not checked. Click [OK]. Create source file with template *C++ File (.cpp)*. Name it *Source.cpp*. The *Location* should be C:\SDL\SDLproject.

**B. Installing SDL2-2.0.8 on Project**

**B.1. Add the Include folder.** Right click on the name of your project, that is SDLproject (if you chose it), and select Properties. Open the C/C++ dropdown menu. Click General > Additional Include Directories > down arrow at the right of the field > *Edit...* in the drop down menu. At the top of the Additional Include Directories window, click the brown folder icon (the first icon). Click the three dots (...) next to the text box that is created. In the *Select Directory* window, navigate C: > SDL > SDL2-2.0.8, and click *include* folder. The *Folder* should be *include*. Click *Select Folder* on the *Select Directory* window and [OK] in the *Additional Include Directories* window.

**B.2. Add the x86 folder.**  Open the *Linker* dropdown menu, and click *General*. Click *Additional Library Directories* entry, and click the down arrow at the right of the field. Click *Edit...* in the dropdown menu. At the top of the *Additional Library Directories* window, click the brown folder icon. Then click the three dots next to the text box that is created. In the *Select Directory* window, navigate C: > SDL > SDL2-2.0.8, and then double click *lib* folder, followed by clicking *x86* folder. The *Folder* is *x86*. Click *Select folder* on *Select Directory* window and [OK] on *Additional Library Directories* window.

**B.3. Add the two library files.** In the *Linker* dropdown menu, click *Input*. Click the *Additional Dependencies* entry > the down arrow at the right of the field > *Edit...* in the dropdown menu. In *Additional Dependencies* window copy and paste *SDL2.lib; SDL2main.lib* in the top-most text box. Click[ [OK] in the *Additional Dependencies* window. In the *Linker* dropdown menu, click System > SubSystem. Click the down arrow and select Console(/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) from the dropdown menu. Click [Apply], then [OK] on the *Property Pages* window.

**B.4. Configure the linker subsystem to console.** In the *Linker* dropdown menu, click System > SubSystem. Click the down arrow and select Console(/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) from the dropdown menu. Click [Apply], then [OK] on the *Property Pages* window.

**B.5. Copy the SDL2.dll file from x86 to your main project file.** Navigate C: > SDL > SDL2-2.0.8 > lib > x86 in file explorer. In x86 folder click SDL2.dll file > right-click > Copy. Navigate to your C: > SDL > SDLproject. Right-click an empty area in *SDLproject* folder, and select *Paste*. The *SDL2.dll* file should now be in your project directory along with your *Source.cpp file* and a few other files created by Visual Studio.

Now you can compile and run your SDL program.

**C. Creating project with SDL project template.**

**C.1. Create project template.**  By Windows's Paint program create icon with file name *SDL*. Go to Visual Studio and open *SDLproject*. On V.S. menu click Project > Export Template.... On *Export template* Wizard check *Project Template...*, if it's not checked. Click *Next >*. On *Select Template Options*, Template name:'s text field, type *SDL*. Click the upper [Browse...] (that one next to *Icon Image:* text field). Navigate to folder *Images*. Click image *SDL*. Click [Open]. Now path of *Icon Image:* is ending with \SDL.png. Click [Finish].

**C.2. Create project with SDL project template.**

**C.2.1.** On V.S. click File > New > Project.... On *New Project* window, click template: *SDL*. In *Name:*'s text field, type: *SDLproject-1*. *Location* is C:\SDL. Be sure *Create directory for solution* is unchecked. Click [OK].

**C.2.2.** On *Solution Explorer*, double click *Source Files*. Click *Source.cpp* > right click > click *Exclude From Project*.

**C.2.3.** Again right click Source Files > Add > New Item.... On *Add New Item - SDLproject-1* window, click *C++ File (.cpp)*. In *Name:*'s text field, type: *Source-1.cpp*. The *Location* is C:\SDL\SDLproject-1. Click *Add*. Now on *Solution Explore*, below *Source Files*, you have *Source-1.cpp* file only.

**C.2.4.** Navigate C: > SDL > SDLproject > click file SDL2.dll > right click > click Copy. Now navigate C: > SDL > SDLproject-1 > click on empty area > right click > click Paste. File *SDL2.dll* is in folder *SDLproject-1* among *Source-1.cpp* and other 4 files.

**C.2.5.** Now you can compile your SDL project. On window *This project is out of date:*, below question *Would you like to build it?* click [Yes].

**D. Remark:** Creating project with SDL-project-template is as creating ordinary C++ project, but two more steps:

**D.1.** In *Solution Explorer*, *Source Files*, source file (*Source.cpp* in the example above) of template project (*SDLproject*, in the example) should be excluded from new project (*SDLproject-1* in example).

**D.2.** File *SDL2.dll* should be copied from template project and pasted in new project.