# How do I sucessfully include SDL2 in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2017, sdl-2

Please, if you think this can be done by yourself (and having tested it), please share steps instead of linking other guides. I have tried the following things in different ways:

Downloaded the SDL2 folder, it contains a lib and include folder.

- Open my empty project containing the simple main function and all that (basic template)
- Open Visual Studio's project properties
- Add the include folder in "Additional Include Directories"
- Add the lib folder in "Additional Library Directories"
- Add the individual library files in "Additional Dependencies"
- Include it

The download I have is from this page: https://www.libsdl.org/download-2.0.php

Under "Development Libraries" and under "Windows" I downloaded the VC.zip one.

Help? Please don't lock the thread, yes I have seen thousands of guides on how to do this. Why you think I ask here? Failure after failure, I'm getting nowhere.

I get a compile error which is something like this nonsense:

> ```
> Error LNK2019 unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function "int __cdecl invoke_main(void)" (?invoke_main@@YAHXZ)
> ```

Here is my code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>

#include <SDL.h>

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    cout << "Hello world!" << endl;

    return 0;

}
```

Comment: _"Failure after failure"_ I you want to get helped, explicitly state what specific _failures_ you're stuck with.

Comment: You didn't link `SDLmain.lib`

Comment: I did link SDL2main.lib

Comment: "something like this nonsense..." It's not nonsense, it's an error message that makes perfect sense to anyone who understands the basic of how a C++ program is put together. Of course we need to know what the actual error is, yeesh

Comment: @JohnSilver: The linker cannot find the definition of main (_main)

Comment: Please edit it into your question, no one will scroll through the comments to see it. The code itself looks ok to me. Probably you're linking your libs incorrectly or using wrong ones.

Comment: I editted it into my question. Linking everything seems very simple and very correct on my end. 3 things to link, library folder to additional libraries, include folder to additional include, and link each file name from lib to Additional Dependencies

Comment: @JohnSilver I'm no SDL expert, but from the linker error it looks like the implementation of `_main()` (note the leading underscore) is missing. You're probably required to provide a definition for that.

Comment: Sorry for sounding dumb about this, but what do I do @user0042, what do you mean by provide a definition for that? how would I do so?

Comment: I'm pretty sure the compile error is just some nonsense stuff from the SDL download. Can anybody here try to successfully use SDL2 in visual studio 2017? It's supposed to be popular, how do they set it up? I'm pretty sure I'm doing stuff right. like the guy in the video, same stuff, only me with error: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Sfn7yOiwJLw

Comment: @user0042 That shouldn't be neccessay. SDL is supposed to work with a normal `main()`.

Comment: @HolyBlackCat Yes, I saw that in some github gist while investigating. Maybe the source shown by the OP isn't a compiled part of the VS2017 project.

Comment: Make sure you set your `SUBSYSTEM` (Configuration Properties -> Linker -> System -> SubSystem) to `CONSOLE` or `WINDOWS`.

Comment: the file from which the error comes from is "MSVCRTD.lib(exe_main.obj)" first line. and then of course there is a second error because of an unresolved external aka the first error, also yeah subsystem has always been console. i even created a new one just now, console->empty project (an empty project with console as subsystem), pasted code and followed the settings instructions, still doesent work.

Comment: What version of VC is the SDL library compiled with?

Comment: see the link I posted, I took the VC.zip one under windows, under development libraries

Comment: I looked at the link and couldn't tell what version they used. You must use libraries compiled with the same version with Visual Studio.

Comment: They use 2.0.5, don't know how old that is

Comment: how do I get visual studio 2015? couldn't find an official download of it

Comment: I have experienced the same problem using visual studio 2012. I went through the tutorial provided via the official site for SDL 3 times ! and I still get the compile time error : "Error 4 error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _main referenced in function ___tmainCRTStartup C:\Users\kiyarash\Desktop\visual studio\SDL_header\SDL_header\MSVCRTD.lib(crtexe.obj) SDL_header
" 
and here is the link to the tutorial :http://www.willusher.io/sdl2%20tutorials/2013/08/15/lesson-0-visual-studio

Comment: I tried in visual studio 2015, still same error, my computer is by the way 64 bit which means I select the x64 folder instead of the x86. Situation unchanged, still can't do anything with SDL.

Comment: I got it to work, after hours. Literally over five hours, at the very least. I got tired of getting SDL to work, so I  tried out SFML instead. That also failed, so I went to the SFML website and checked the versions, and it stated under the version links that I should only take 64-bit version downloads if I HAVE to, and don't take 64 bit just because my PC is 64 bits. So I downloaded SFML 32 bit, it worked. Then I thought it might be the same with SDL.. and it was, just that they were pretty bad at informing me of that. Also, I also had to say main(int argc, char** argv) instead of main()

Comment: To summarize, the main problem was that I needed to take the 32 bit version, and not the 64 bit one, even though my PC is 64 bit. SDL is pretty bad at documenting/stating that, but thank god I tried out SFML so they could make it clear. By the way, why do I have to say int main(int argc, char** argv) instead of int main() ? Never got that.

Comment: thanks for your endeavour and discovery! it worked for me too!  it is strange that we must use the x86 library version. I have no answer for the main() question either . :(

Comment: [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42680820/is-it-possible-to-put-the-sdl-lib-dll-and-header-files-somewhere-so-i-can-ju) you can get the answer. Regards.

Answer (score -1):

That happens because SDL uses `#define main SDL_main` and replaces the main function with it's own version. Linking with SDL2main.lib, which contains the implementation should get rid of the error. Alternatively you can add `#undef main` right before your main function.

Comment: OP said they're already linking to `SDL2main.lib` in the comments.